# If for any external point, exactly two tangents can be drawn to an algebraic curve, must the curve be a conic?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, algebraic-curves

Yesterday, my teacher, while proving Poncelet's theorem, seemed to use the fact that if from any external point (external meaning, I assume $f(x,y)>0$ where $f$ is the polynomial of two variables corresponding to the curve), exactly two tangents to the curve can be drawn, then the curve is a conic. Is this true? If so, I've not been able to rigorously prove it. Any help will be appreciated. Maybe some additional conditions will be required, like nonsingularity of the curve. I'm not sure.

Comment: So you’re doing projective geometry over $\Bbb R$ only? I don’t like the idea of external point, even there. Don’t $f$ and $-f$ define the same curve?

Comment: Will Jagy and I probably would agree that the teacher’s statement sounds as if it will be true once it’s stated in the correct generality, allowing irrational (complex, in this case) slopes for your tangents. No talk of “external”, please. But this would be a consequence of a much deeper theorem, far beyond the level of the course you’re taking.

Answer (score 1):

$$  x^4 + x^2 y^2 + y^4 = 1  $$
is not a conic. All your condition requires is that the curve bound a strictly convex region.

Comment: I’m saying yeah, but… In the sense of the geometry of the Euclidean plane, I guess so, but in some algebrogeometric sense, don’t you expect four tangents to your curve from any point, counting multiplicities and looking for slopes to your lines that are not rational over the base?

Comment: @Lubin, looked up Poncelet's on Wikipedia, which I did not do last night. You are certainly correct, this should all be stated in algebraic geometry terms, generally not familiar to me. So, the question is quite off the mark as stated. Is there an interpretation that makes something similar to the question correct?

Comment: I have to admit that I’m over my head here too. For a moment I thought that a pair of intersecting lines did not satisfy the stated condition, but it occurs to me that any line through the vertex, counted twice, might fill the bill. I think it highly likely that if properly stated in algebrogeometric lingo, the teacher’s claim is true, omitting the “external” bit. It seems clear to me that from a point inside a circle, you can draw two tangents, but with complex, nonreal, slopes.

Comment: @Lubin, understood. The main thing is that we do not know what the teacher actually said, we have some paraphrase that does not seem to have any interpretation as an ingredient in a proof of Poncelet's porism.